# Find rational representation of a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, power-series, rational-functions

I need to find a rational function $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials, which value is the same as $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (2n+1)z^{2n}$ on its convergence domain.

I found $\rho=1$, but now I'm stuck. I thought about setting $2n = m$ but I'm pretty sure it would change the series value. I saw in class a way to go from the rational function to the series, but I can't seem to be able to apply it in the opposite direction (it implied factoring the polynomial with its roots $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, but here we don't know the degree of the polynomials).

I didn't try separating the series in two, but can I even do that?

Thank you guys!

Comment: This looks like the derivative of $(z^{2n+1}).$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (2n+1)z^{2n} = \big(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{2n+1}\big)'$$

$$=\big({z\over 1-z^2}\big)'=...$$

Comment: Thank you, I feel dumb, as it's the number one "trick" you learn in real analysis 1, and I probably spaced out because it's "complex analysis" so why not forget about everything huh. I'll post my solution for future readers in a few minutes!

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (2n+1)z^{2n}=\biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{2n+1}\biggr)'$,
- $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty z^{2n+1}=z\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (z^2)^{n}$.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment above